# Determine if a variable is declared in a class

Tags: java

I have a class, say Test; within that is a nested static class, say TestParams.

TestParams only contains some String variables referring to the Test class

The problem which I am facing is that, in the setters of Test class, I need to verify if the set parameter is one of the params declared in the Params class.

The scenario is shown in the code below:

```
public class Test {

  protected String n;
  protected int num;

  public static class TestParams {
    public static final String PARAM_N="n";
    public static final String PARAM_NUM="num";
  }

  public void setParam(String key, Object value) {
    // Need to check here the if key is defined in TestParams
    // keep adding conditions to IF statement when more params added??
    if(key.equals(TestParams.PARAM_N) || (key.equals(TestParams.PARAM_NUM))
      // Do some stuff
  }

}
```

Is there any method to replace the IF statement with multiple conditions? (something like *if key in TestParams()* or maybe some other design for the code structure?

Comment: You can try reflection

Comment: Make an enum and use, `Enum.valueOf(String) != null`?

Comment: But isn't it easy just have `Set<String>` with all possible keys and use `contains` method?

Comment: Your `if` is fine.. stick with it.

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII Isn't it throws exception if you pass wrong string?

Comment: @MarounMaroun as long as you have 2 keys yes, but think about 20.

Comment: Have you considered using a Map<String, Object> to store all your parameters?

Comment: @T-Fowl its not about storing the parameters. Its about validating whether the String parameter; whether its valid or not

Comment: @gopi1410 In that case I would strongly encourage you, as aioobe said in his answer, to re-think your design. It would be a lot easier and more efficient to store all the _valid_ parameters in a `List<String>` then just call the `list.contains(String)` method.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the particular problem you're asking about, I see no other way than to use reflection:

```
private boolean isValidKey(String str) {
    for (Field f : TestParams.class.getFields())
        try {
            if (f.get(null).equals(str))
                return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return false;
}
```

Though I would strongly encourage you to rethink the design.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all this fields in a Map like

```
public class Test {

  protected String n;
  protected int num;

  public static class TestParams {
    public static Map<String, Object> PARAMS;

    // This will initialize the map statically
    static {
      PARAMS.put("PARAM_N", "n");
      PARAMS.put("PARAM_NUM", "num");
    }
  }

  public void setParam(String key, Object value) {
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : TestParams.PARAMS){
      if(entry.getValue().equals(key)){
        //do stuff
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection could be a solution:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Test {

  protected String n;
  protected int num;

  private Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();

  public Test(){
      Field[] fields = TestParams.class.getDeclaredFields();
      for (Field field : fields) {
          if ( Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) ) {
              try {
                params.put(field.getName(), field.get(null));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          } 
      }
  }

  public static class TestParams {
    public static final String PARAM_N="n";
    public static final String PARAM_NUM="num";
  }

  public void setParam(String key, Object value) {
      if( params.containsValue(key)){
          // do ....
      }else{
          // do ...
      }
  }

}
```

1 - you loop over **static** variables in TestParams

2 - save these variables in a `map<paramName,ParamValue>` in your Test Class

3 - in your `SetParam` method you ask if a value exists in the map

Answer (score 0):

There is such a mechanism, [BeanInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/beaninfo.html) or [this](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/javabeans/beaninfo/index.html), that associates a simple POJO (bean) class with meta information in a separate class. Its major usage nowadays is providing two-column property windows to edit field of some POJO class. Using [PropertyDescriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html).

Now, BeanInfo needs some tooling, and that all depends on your use case. The documentation out there never was very appealing, touching on Serializable and such. But it provides functionality, you would do hard to reinvent.

Maybe try it out first for a JComponent, the possibilities like field validation still need some coding.